# Bounded subset proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Having trouble with this proof. I believe it revolves around using the Archimedean principle, all hints will help.I am having trouble thinking about how to pick a value for $n$ that contains both the supremum and infimum of the set $A$.Also can somebody help show how to prove the opposite direction of the biconditional?

Problem:

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Prove that A is bounded iff there is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A \subseteq (-n,n)$

Attempt $\implies$ (direction)

Let $ A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Assume $A$ is bounded

Since A is bounded there is a greatest lower bound call it $m$.

Then $m\leq x$ for all $x \in A$. Also there is a greatest lower upper bound, call it $y$. Then $y \geq x$ for all $x \in A$.Also $m,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Take $max\{|m|,|y|\}$

Case1 $|y|>|m|$
By the Archimedean principle if $y \notin \mathbb{N},  \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>y$.

Then $(-n,n)$ contains the interval containing $m$ and $y$.

and $A \subseteq(-n,n)$

Now im lost since the Archimedean property is only useful for upper bounds. I would like to take the case where $|m|>|y|$ and state there is a natural number less than $m$ and use this. Is my approach completely incorrect? If so can I get a hint to steer me in the right direction? Also I just sort of made up the statement "take $max\{|m|,|y|\}$" and have never seen this before. Is it all completely wrong?

Comment: Note that ceiling function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceiling_function ) is defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $n=\lceil\max(|m|,|y|)\rceil$.

Comment: @zongxiangyi then after I have done this and I have my value for $n$ can I just say $A \subseteq (-n,n)$ and is the forward direction proven?

Comment: Of course, you have $-n<m$ and $n>y$. Thus $-n<x<n$ for $x \in A$.

Comment: @zongxiang yi Then to prove the reverse direction I assume $A \subset (-n,n)$ and need to show this implies A is bounded?

Comment: Yes. $A\subset(-n,n)$ implies $-n<x<n$ for $x\in A$. Obviously $-n\le x\le n$ for $x\in A$. Hence $-n$ is a lower bound and $n$ is a upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct and completely fine.

It's valid to use $\max\{|m|,|y|\}$ and I expect no errors with its usage in your complete proof.

The Archimedean property can be used to construct an integer less than m. Maybe it will be useful to prove that if $N$ is an integer, $m$ is a real number, and $|m| \leq N$ then $-N < m$. The statement $-|m| \leq m \leq |m|$ might also be useful to prove.

Comment: Can I do what zongxiang yi said and take $\lceil$ max$(|m|,|y|)$ $\rceil$ and take this value for $n$ and successfully conclude $A \subset (-n,n)$?

Comment: @Eastcoastdancer That would also be correct.